# Would Rodrigues' rotation formula apply in this case?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Suppose I am given two unit vectors starting from origin in three dimensions, $\vec{v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z)$ and $\vec{u}=(\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi, \cos\theta) $, which is just the spherical representation of the end point of the vector $\vec{u}$. Given the knowledge about the two vectors, I know that the angle between them is
$$\cos\theta_0 = v_x\sin\theta\cos\phi + v_y\sin\theta\sin\phi + v_z\cos\theta~.$$
However, suppose I want to know all vectors that make angle $\theta_0$ with $\vec{v}$, i.e I want to know all the $(\theta, \phi)$. In this case, would [Rodrigue's rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) apply?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
P_{n}(z)=\frac{1}{2^n n!} \frac{d^{n}}{dz^n} (z^2-1)^n.
\end{eqnarray*}
What is Rodrigues's Formula ? $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Sorry, have a look at the edited link now in the question.

Comment: Yes, you could certainly use the rotation formula as part of the parameterization of the cone.